# Highcharts smooth transition on data update using Angular and ng-highcharts

Tags: angularjs, highcharts, highcharts-ng

I've recently made a prototype of a highchart that works strictly in jquery. I had a bunch of spaghetti code, but I also had a nice transitional animation when selecting a controller that would animate the chart and update the series. In short, it was done like so...

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(chartOptions);
// ...
$('select#dropdown').change(function(){
  // ...
  chart.series[0].setData(/*data*/, false);
  chart.series[1].setData(/*data*/, false);
  chart.series[2].setData(/*data*/, false);
  // ...
  chart.redraw();
}
```

So the chart (1) initialized on page load, (2) Takes an argument from a dropdown box (3) decides what the new value is for a given series and (4) smoothly redraws the chart to that value.

My problem is that I'm having a very difficult time re-producing this in angular. Especially highcharts-ng, which seems to have every example under the sun EXCEPT updating existing points.

http://pablojim.github.io/highcharts-ng/examples/example.html

There are things like adding series, deleting series etc.. What about UPDATING a series? What if we wanted a series tied to a scope variable, which was constantly changing? How would I make a $scope.$watch on the drop-down box tell the chart to update the points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to update the data array in the series and the highcharts will take care of the smooth transition. 
for example:

```
 $scope.chartConfig.series[0].data = rnd;
```

**Here I have updated the example for you to show smooth update transition**: 
 [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rSHN4/1/)

**And an example with Drop Down and watch :**
[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shaunakv1/Ubdjq/1/)

Hope that helps. let me know if you have any questions on how it works.

Comment: Shaunak I do have one additional question: What if $scope.chartConfig.series[0].data needed to be equal to a value that was created by a function... In other words, I've got 2 arguments (the object that holds the data, and the route that we're traversing into):

`//Let a propertyExpr string define a traversal route into an object
$scope.dataResult = function(obj, propertyExpr) {
      return $parse(propertyExpr)(obj);
    }`

`$scope.chartConfig.series[0].data = dataResult(obj, exp);` How would I make the watch function update the dataResult that is equal to series[0]?

Thank you very much!!

Comment: Since you answered my question, I'm going to go ahead and mark this one as answered and post a secondary question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22882107/scope-watch-make-it-return-a-function-on-another-scope

Comment: I've done this but don't see any smooth transition. None of the fiddles you linked have a smooth transition on the bars like a vanilla series[0].data[i].update(new_value) does.

Comment: @DaveBriand while Highchart updates their libraries pretty fast, I still see animated transations on the fiddles I linked in the answer. I use the same method in plenty apps I have online. Can you please create a fiddle to the kind of animation you are talking about using the `update` ? May be that will help figuring out what the difference is.

Comment: @Shaunak I've dumped highcharts for d3. I had figured it out but had to change some of the code in angular-highcharts when the series was updating. Can't remember what - sorry :)